# Can't ping eth1 via eth0

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking

I have two virtual machines with CentOS 7 installed.
Each VM has two NICs and two IP addresses.

ip configuration of VM1:

```
    eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.255.255.5/30 brd 172.255.255.7 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4f07:27f6:5839:d257/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:4b:2f:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.11.111.254/21 brd 10.11.111.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d64c:aeee:1111:16d5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

route of VM1:

```
10.11.104.0/21 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.111.111.254 metric 101
172.255.255.4/30 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.255.255.5 metric 100
```

ip configuration of VM2:

```
   eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.255.255.6/30 brd 172.255.255.7 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::35e3:6bb7:918e:6bca/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:25:38:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.1.210/24 brd 10.10.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5ec3:f912:51a5:761c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

route of VM2:

```
10.10.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.1.210 metric 101
172.255.255.4/30 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.255.255.6 metric 100
```

I can ping from VM1(172.255.255.5,10.11.111.254) to 172.255.255.6 and can ping from VM2(172.255.255.6, 10.10.1.210) to 172.255.255.5.

The problem is, I want to ping from VM1(172.255.255.5,10.11.111.254) to 10.10.1.210, so I add a route in VM1

```
ip route add 10.10.1.210 via 172.255.255.6
```

so the route of VM1 is:

```
10.10.1.210 via 172.255.255.6 dev eth0
10.11.104.0/21 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.111.111.254 metric 101
172.255.255.4/30 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.255.255.5 metric 100
```

But I still can't ping from VM1 to 10.10.1.210.

So, where am I wrong?

By the way, I have disabled SELinux and firewalld on all my machines.

1. ip route get 10.10.1.210:

   `10.10.1.210 via 172.255.255.6 dev eth0 src 172.255.255.5 
       cache`
2. tcpdump -e -nn -i eth0 'icmp' on VM1:

   `20:47:00.147549 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 48, length 64
   20:47:01.147541 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 49, length 64
   20:47:02.147543 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 50, length 64
   20:47:03.147551 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 51, length 64`
3. VM1, iptables-save -c :

   ````
   *security
   :INPUT ACCEPT [5440:12841065]
   :FORWARD ACCEPT [2:144]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [28968:2491805]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   *raw
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [5456:12843525]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [28969:2491905]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   *mangle
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [5456:12843525]
   :INPUT ACCEPT [5440:12841065]
   :FORWARD ACCEPT [2:144]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [28969:2491905]
   :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [28970:2491949]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   *filter
   :INPUT ACCEPT [5440:12841065]
   :FORWARD ACCEPT [2:144]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [28968:2491805]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019
   *nat
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [41:6031]
   :INPUT ACCEPT [26:3643]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [196:139164]
   :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [197:139236]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:48:08 2019```
   ````
4. VM2, iptables-save -c :

   ````
   *nat
   :PREROUTING ACCEPT [151:139500]
   :INPUT ACCEPT [136:137067]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [126:76110]
   :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [126:76110]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:51:19 2019
   # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon May 20 20:51:19 2019
   *filter
   :INPUT ACCEPT [22121:14364143]
   :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [21468:1823390]
   COMMIT
   # Completed on Mon May 20 20:51:19 2019```
   ````
5. tcpdump -e -nn -i eth0 'icmp' on VM2

   `20:53:50.348475 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 459, length 64
   20:53:50.348501 fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7 > fa:16:3e:0b:03:33, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.10.1.210 > 172.255.255.5: ICMP echo reply, id 4116, seq 459, length 64
   20:53:51.348443 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 460, length 64
   20:53:51.348501 fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7 > fa:16:3e:0b:03:33, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.10.1.210 > 172.255.255.5: ICMP echo reply, id 4116, seq 460, length 64
   20:53:52.348432 fa:16:3e:0b:03:33 > fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.255.255.5 > 10.10.1.210: ICMP echo request, id 4116, seq 461, length 64
   20:53:52.348456 fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7 > fa:16:3e:0b:03:33, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.10.1.210 > 172.255.255.5: ICMP echo reply, id 4116, seq 461, length 64`

Comment: what is the result of `ip r s` ? have you set default route ?

Comment: Enable IP forwarding on VM2 if not enabled: [ip-forwarding](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux), try turning iptables off while testing, or check their rules.

Comment: no default route on both machines. ip forwarding(net.ipv4.ip_forward) is enabled on both machines.

Comment: eth1's IP are not in same range, you won't be able to connect directly.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to troubleshoot.

1. Check the actual routes. On VM1 run `ip route get 10.10.1.210`. It should return valid route.
2. Your setup doesn't require enabled forwarding in the current state.
3. Run the `tcpdump -ni eth0 'icmp'` on VM1. You should see outgoing `icmp echo requests`. If you don't see them, then they are either filtered or routed through other interface.
4. Anyway check the firewall with command `iptables-save -c`.
5. Run the `tcpdump -ni eth0 'icmp'` on VM2. Do you see incoming `icmp echo request` and outgoing `icmp echo reply`?

If the steps above haven't helped, paste the outputs of commands from them into the question, and I'll extend the answer.

Comment: I have pasted the output of each step into the question.  VM1 only has `icmp echo requests`, VM2 have `icmp echo request` and `icmp echo reply`.

Comment: It's interesting case. Replies are losing somewhere in hypervisor bridge. Run 'ping -I 10.10.1.210 172.255.255.5'. Is it pinging successfully? Check the tcpdump captures.

Comment: 'ping -I 10.10.1.210 172.255.255.5' doesn't work, neither does `ping -I 10.11.111.254 172.255.255.6`. the capture output is too long, so I put it in a another answer, please check, thank you.

Comment: Have you seen errors at run `ping -I 10.10.1.210 172.255.255.5` on VM2 or there was just silence?

Comment: no error, just silence

Comment: Have you run the tcpdump on VM2 in the same moment? Have you seen some activity in it?

Comment: I notice the above icmp capture results, 10.10.1.210 and its mac address doesn't match, 10.10.1.210's mac address is fa:16:3e:25:38:9a, not fa:16:3e:7a:3c:e7. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93867/discussion-between-anton-danilov-and-gary-allen).